# detection with contour and show it Error

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, shadow

I'm try to remove shadow with threshold and detect the motion on live camera .
here is my program :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:

    t=cam.read()[1]
    t0=cv2.cvtColor(cam.read()[1],cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    t1=cv2.cvtColor(cam.read()[1],cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    t2=cv2.cvtColor(cam.read()[1],cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

    a1=cv2.absdiff(t0,t1)
    a2=cv2.absdiff(t1,t2)
    b=cv2.bitwise_and(a1,a2)

    ret,thresh0=cv2.threshold(b,30,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    thresh1=cv2.bitwise_and(t1,thresh0)
    contours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(thresh0,1,2)
    cnt=contours[0]
    x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    img=cv2.rectangle(t1,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

    cv2.imshow("winName",t1)
    cv2.imshow("detect",img)


    key=cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key==27:
        cv2.destroyAllwindow()
        break
print "End"
```

But I encounter the following errors:

```
in line ( cv2.imshow("detect",img) ) which stop with this error : 
    cv2.imshow("thresh",img)

error: /home/rayannik/opencv-2.4.10/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:261:    
error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

If we ignore that line it's will be work just when something move always on front of camera otherwise stop with this error:

```
cnt=contours[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the line :

```
img=cv2.rectangle(t1,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
```

Basically the `cv2.rectangle()` method changes the input mat in-place and returns `None`, So the parameter `t1` is modified in-place and since the return Type is `None`, so the variable `img` which you are using in `imshow()` is `None`.

Remove the `cv2.imshow("detect",img)` as the changes are already reflected in the `cv2.imshow("winName",t1)` window.

Secondly, `cnt=contours[0]` is raising `IndexOutOfBounds` error because, `cv2.findCountours()` didn't found any contours in the input Mat. You must always pass only **BinaryImage** to the `cv2.findCountours` method, and also check before accessing the countours as:

```
if (len(contours) > 0):  # this condition would prevent the IndexOutOfBounds error
    cnt=contours[0]
```